# Upload JPG Image To Parse Server Failing

Tags: json, swift, parse-server

I am trying to upload image files to parse server. I can upload png files correctly but if i **select jpg file then i am getting error** like this;

> Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."

I am using theese codes for upload images;

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
    let imageExt         = imageUrl.pathExtension
    var type = 1
    if imageExt == "PNG" {
        type = 0
    }else if imageExt == "JPG" {
        type = 1
    }
    profilePicture.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    self.uploadImageToParse(image: profilePicture.image!,imageType:type)
}

func uploadImageToParse(image:UIImage,imageType:Int) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "cls_kullanicilar")
    query.getObjectInBackground(withId: uObjectId) { (object, error) in
        if error == nil {
            if let object = object {
                if imageType == 0 {
                    let fname = String(self.randomString(length: 12)+".png")
                    let imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
                    let parseFile = PFFile(name: fname, data: imgData!)
                    object["profilePhoto"] = parseFile
                    //object["profil_foto"] = fname
                    object.saveInBackground(block: { (result, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    })
                }else if imageType == 1 {
                    let fname = String(self.randomString(length: 12)+".jpg")
                    let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
                    let parseFile = PFFile(name: fname, data: imgData!)
                    object["profilePhoto"] = parseFile
                    //object["profil_foto"] = fname
                    object.saveInBackground(block: { (result, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }else{
            print("HATA")
        }
    }
}
```

How can i handle this ? Thank you all.

Comment: under the PFFile you can also pass the contentType parameter. Can you please try to set it to "image/jpeg" and try again ?

Comment: @RanHassid i changed ppfile like this PFFile(name: fname, data: imgData!, contentType:"image/jpg") but i get same error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution my problem.

I increase my Nginx upload size. My bad. I can not think everything sometimes.